# Is using an uniqueidentifier for the primary key more secure?

Tags: sql, security, web-applications, ssl

I am using SSL for my web application. Would using an uniqueidentifier as the primary key for sensitive data add any extra security or would it just slow things down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, in the same way that a cardboard lock is more secure than a paper lock.

If you are using security by obscurity, that is the only thing preventing someone from seeing something they shouldn't is that they don't know a primary key value, then yes. it adds a little bit of security.

That said, your efforts would be much better applied to locking down the data through affirmative means instead of relying on the user not guessing an ID. Security by obscurity is especially vulnerable to sniffing attacks.

Comment: I up-voted. But sometimes people wonder, "Well isn't a password also security by obscurity? You rely on the password being hard to guess, what's the difference?"  My reply would be that every user sharing the same password -- or not -- is a big difference. When they don't share, you can change or revoke for some but not all. Another difference is that passwords (usually/hopefully) aren't transmitted in clear text and subject to sniffing. Would that be your reply, too?

Comment: A more analogous comparison would be having a site with a username and no password.  Guessing a username (or an identity value) is much easier than guessing a combination of a username and a password. Still, technically you could say that almost any form of security relies on obscuring some information unless you are talking about physical security of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wondering whether to use int vs GUID for a PK, Jeff Atwood has a blog post on the subject that could be of some help to you.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html

As David said, integer keys are much nicer as URL's for readability sake. Especially if you think someone will be tweeting or linking to a post or profile. **www.site.com/users/233** is a lot easier to read/type than **www.site.com/users/C87FC84A-EE47-47EE-842C-29E969AC5131**

But it really won't add much of a "security" benefit.

Comment: As a general rule, it's a bad idea to publicly expose internal, synthetic database identifiers, in URLs or anywhere else. Use a natural key publicly. For instance, instead of `www.site.com/users/233`, use `www.site.com/users/jsmith`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about something that's visible in the URL, then I'd say "Yes, It's a *little* better".

The reason I say that is that it is really easy to manually manipulate a url and with just an integer value, you can just change it easily ans see what you get.  It's less likely to get a valid uniqueidentifier using this method.

That said, uniqueidentifiers can be predicted, and I believe an automated system would be able to crack it.  You'd be adding a level of complexity to make your site a less attractive target, but it's not a complete solution for anything.

for more info see: http://www.google.com/search?q=direct+object+reference&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=

IMHO the trade-off of added complexity isn't worth it unless what you're protecting is really not all that valuable.